# How are affinely (in)dependent vectors in $\mathbb R^n$ arranged in space?

Tags: linear-algebra, affine-geometry

Consider a finite set of vectors $\{v_i\}_i\subset\mathbb R^n$.

This set is linearly independent if $\sum_k \alpha_k v_k=0$ implies $\alpha_k=0$.
Geometrically, I understand linear dependence as stating that a set of vectors is contained in a hyperplane passing through the origin.

On the other hand, we say that $\{v_i\}_i$ are *affinely dependent* if $\sum_k \alpha_k v_k=0$ for $\alpha_k$ not all zero *and* such that $\sum_k\alpha_k=0$.
Is there a similar geometrical intuition to visualise when a set $\{v_i\}_i$ is affinely dependent/independent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your characterization of linear (in)dependence is not quite correct. Every set of vectors is contained in some kind of hyperplane through the origin, namely its span.

Instead, I would say that a finite set of vectors is linearly dependent if they lie in a hyperplane through the origin whose dimension is less than the number of vectors in the set.

And in a similar vein, a finite set of points in $\mathbb R^n$ is affinely dependent if it lies in a hyperplane whose dimension is less than the number of points in the set **minus 1**. Thus, 3 different points on a line are affinely dependent, but 2 different points on a line are affinely independent.

There is another nice geometric picture of affine independence:

- a pair of points is affinely independent if it is the endpoint set of a line segment (which occurs if and only if the two points in that pair are unequal)
- a triple of points is affinely independent if it is the vertex set of a triangle
- a quadruple of points is affinely independent if it is the vertex set of a tetrahedron
- a $k$-tuple of points is affinely independent if it is the vertex set of a $k-1$ dimensional [simplex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex).

Comment: Nice. I suspect that OP was using "hyperplane" to mean "codimension 1 hyperplane", and that the set of vectors was supposed to have $n$ elements in it implicitly. So this was a good chance for OP to learn not only that hyperplane can mean more than that, but also that the number of points matters.

Comment: To Lee's nice geometric picture, let me add an algorithmic restatement. A triple of (distinct) points is *dependent* if it's not the vertex set of a triangle, in which case the set of all convex combinations of its elements forms a line segment...and one of the three points must therefore be expressible as a convex combination of the others. That's more generally true: in an affinely dependent set (which must have at least two elements!), one of the points is a convex combination of the others. The algorithmic application: "so you can remove one of the points without changing the convex hull."

Comment: thanks. Indeed, I was not taking into account that smaller numbers of vectors can also (obviously) be linearly/affinely independent. This is very useful. The observation "affinely dependent means one of the points is convex combination of the others" is also a very nice one.

Answer (score 1):

As @runway44 says, affinely-dependent means "they're all in hyperplane", although possibly a hyperplane that does not contain the origin. To see this quickly, take the $k+1$ vectors
$$
v_0, v_1 \ldots, v_k
$$
with $$
\sum a_i v_i = 0, \sum a_i = 1
$$
and subtract $v_0$ from each of $v_1, \ldots, v_k$ to get $w_1, \ldots, w_k$.

Then the vectors $w_k$ all lie on a parallel hyperplane through the origin. (It's worth doing the algebra to establish this yourself).

Or, to put it in a more classical form, if we take $v_0$ as the origin of a new coordinate system, then the remaining $v_i$ vectors all lie in a hyperplane.